# Cannot zoom in and move the image inside a frame

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two images,
The first image is the frame in **png** format
And the main image .
My problem is cannot zoom in and move the image because its layer is before the frame
How can I apply ***InteractiveViewer*** on the main image only?

[image]

```
 Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children:<Widget>[
        InteractiveViewer(
                maxScale: 3.5,
                minScale: 0.1,
                boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/1.png"))
        ),
        Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Image.asset("assets/images/frame.png",
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight, color: frameColor(category)),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your top layer (the picture frame) widget with an `IgnorePointer`, it will ignore user gestures, so the bottom widget can properly receive those gestures.

For example:

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    InteractiveViewer( // <--- `InteractiveViewer` here!
      child: FlutterLogo(size: 200),
    ),
    IgnorePointer( // <--- `IgnorePointer` here! 
      child: Icon(
        Icons.repeat,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 400,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```